# Python django escape unicode

Tags: python, django, unicode, django-templates

I want to escape unicode.

My python script contains:

```
unicode_str = u'\u8fb0'
```

My template file contains:

```
{{ unicode_str|escape }}
```

It results in a KeyError.

How do I escape unicode characters?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have the full traceback?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

The inbuilt escape filter is not designed to handle Unicode. Write your own.

Comment: Can you point me to a site somewhere that at least gives me an example of how to do that?

Comment: I guess I would start from the [django doc](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters)

Answer (score 0):

In your python code you can use the following to escape unicode when passing an object as a whole:

```
import json
dict = {'name': 'John Doe'}
json.dumps(dict)
```